# Scoll to top on click

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I try to scroll to top of sticky tab navigation and it seems that the function runs on pageload, not only on click. I get a unwanted flicker and a scroll to bottom on page load. What could be wrong with my code?

```
        jQuery('ul.wc-tabs li a').click(function() {
            var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
        if ( parseInt( width ) <= 768 ) {
            jQuery('ul.wc-tabs li').removeClass('active');
                      jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(".woocommerce-tabs").offset().top}, 1000);
            return;
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. WooCommerce "clicks" the event on pageload by itself.
Working code (except for the first tab):

```
         jQuery('ul.wc-tabs li:not(:first-child) a').click(function() {
                var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
        if ( parseInt( width ) <= 768 ) {
            jQuery('ul.wc-tabs li').removeClass('active');
                      jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(".woocommerce-tabs").offset().top}, 100);
            return;
        }
    } );
```